# Optimal algorithm for distance between one point and all others in a grid

Tags: algorithm, geometry, coordinates, discrete-mathematics, micro-optimization

In a grid of pixels, I wish to calculate the **euclidean distance** from one chosen pixel to all other pixels.

This could also be thought of as finding the euclidean distance between one point in a 2D grid coordinate system and all other points.

Now, the naive solution is to iterate over the grid and calculate the distance between each pixel and the chosen pixel using Pythagorean addition (the square root of the sum of two squares):

```
for (int y = 0, x; y < gridHeight; ++y) {
    for (x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x) {
        dist[x][y] = sqrt((chosenPixelX - x)^2 + (chosenPixelY - y)^2);
    }
}
```

...which incurs a `sqrt()` operation for each pixel...

I'm aware of approximations to [Pythagorean addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_max_plus_beta_min_algorithm), but can we go further and exploit the fact that the points/coordinates are on a grid and we're iterating in a known manner (namely +1 unit in the x axis) to calculate/approximate euclidean distance on a rolling basis and thereby avoid a call to `sqrt()` for each coordinate?

[image]
*Example: could d2 be calculated/approximated by using d1? Green denotes the chosen pixel.*

Comment: SIMD stuff eats this up in no time.  Worst case is find the distances squared and do a bunch of sqrt calls at once.  Also, symmetries around horizontal, vertical, and diagonal axis in regards to your starting point - example: the point below and to the right of d2 are the same.  Also, Horizontal/Vertical distances don't need sqrt - just subtract the coordinates.

Comment: Grids usually have reasonable size, so it is worth to precalculate distances for all possible `delta_x,delta_y` and store them in table. But how are you going to use these distances??

Answer (score 3):

Because you are on a grid, you only need to calculate the distance for the absolute value of the distance of each grid point -> (1,1) == (-1,-1) == (-1, 1) == (1, -1).  Further, because of diagonal symmetries, matching values in the pairs also don't need to be calculated -> (2,3) == (3,2) == (-2,3) == etc. .  Finally, anytime calculation has a 0 for a value, you just take the other value -> (3,0) == 3.

With all these tricks, you can cut out at least 87% of the calculation and even more of the square roots.

Even better, if you know the max size of your grid beforehand and can afford the memory, this can all be pre-calculated at compile time into a simple 2D lookup.  This is how we used to do sin/cos calculations in the old days - 45 degrees of lookup data and handle symmetries with absolute values and a `90 - angle` if above 45 degrees after abs.

But...  is it faster to do all these compares and look ups from memory to get the values you are going to cache or is it just faster to use a modern CPU to do the calculations in parallel on multiple pieces of data without needing lookups?  I'd have to test, but I'd start with the simpler, iteration without all these tricks to begin with.